# sbt Managed dependency retrieving wrong version

Tags: java, maven, sbt, ivy

I'm using SBT via the Play framework and I'm running into an issue with the manage dependencies in the build.sbt file.

My build.sbt file:

```
name := "name"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
javaEbean,
cache,
"de.undercouch" % "bson4jackson" % "2.1.0" force(),
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.1.0" force(),
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.1.0" force(),
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.1.0" force(),
"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.11.3",
"org.jongo" % "jongo" % "0.4",
"uk.co.panaxiom" %% "play-jongo" % "0.6.0-jongo0.4",
"org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-client" % "2.4",
"org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-common" % "2.4",
"org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-server" % "2.4",
"org.glassfish.jersey.containers" % "jersey-container-jdk-http" % "2.4"
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

When I try building on my production environment (Ubuntu) I get the error that:
    M[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.glassfish.jersey.core#jersey-client;2.4 ...[0m

```
M[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.glassfish.jersey.core#jersey-common;2.4 ...[0m

M[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving javax.ws.rs#javax.ws.rs-api;2.0 ...[0m

M[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving javax.annotation#javax.annotation-api;1.2 ...[0m

M[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-api;2.2.0-b21 ...[0m
M[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-utils;2.4 ...[0m
[0m[[33mwarn[0m] [0m    module not found: org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-utils;2.4[0m
[0m[[33mwarn[0m] [0m==== local: tried[0m
[0m[[33mwarn[0m] [0m  /opt/play/repository/local/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils/2.4/ivys/ivy.xml[0m
[0m[[33mwarn[0m] [0m==== Maven2 Local: tried[0m
[0m[[33mwarn[0m] [0m  file:/root/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4/hk2-utils-2.4.pom[0m
```

Interestingly enough, this build with no problem on my development environment (also Ubuntu and I believe running the same versions of everything used on the production environment.)

It seems like the problem lies in sbt trying to retrieve version 2.4 of hk2-utils, which does not exist.  I tracked this down to the hk2-api package which contains the following in its POM file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
  <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>    
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I believe that what is occurring is that `${project.version}` is being set as 2.4 on my production environment (which is the version number of jersey-client at the root of this dependency tree) instead of using the version number of it's immediate predecessor. `org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-api;2.2.0-b21`.

I was wondering if this was an error with sbt, an error with my sbt configuration, or what.  I was also wondering if there was any way to fix it on my end through a configuration option or somehow changing the POM for hk2-api.

Comment: Which version of sbt and Play are you using? There's a similar issue reported on sbt project [sbt/sbt#647](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/647) and I just spent some time trying to reproduce it and I couldn't with sbt 0.13.0.

Comment: I'm using Play 2.2.0 with sbt 0.13.0

Comment: Hi Eugene, I have just encountered the same error with sbt 0.13.5. It seems to be the version of jersey-client that is causing the problem. If I use "org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-client" % "2.11" then I encounter the problem but if I bump it to "org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-client" % "2.12" then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not overly familiar with POMS and how they work, so I can't explain why the module is resolved with that version. However I reproduced your problem, and have got a workaround that you can add to your SBT settings.

```
dependencyOverrides ~= { overrides => 
  overrides + "org.glassfish.hk2" % "hk2-utils" % "2.2.0-b21" 
}
```

The dependencyOverrides setting in sbt lets you force a specific version of a dependency, irrelevant of what version is specified elsewhere, either transitively or explicitly. In fact, it works even if the dependency is pulled in purely transitively, as is the case here. (Documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#forcing-a-revision-without-introducing-a-dependency)

Adding this to your build.sbt should force hk2-utils to be resolved with the 2.2.0-b21 version, without actually adding it as a direct dependency of your project.

Comment: Thanks!  This beats just dumping everything in lib/ and passing a handful of jars around.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I was building custom version of sbt dependency. I had a version conflict that was causing bogus version switching during compile. After cleaning .ivy2/cache sbt started to catching my local package just fine.